# Git gui not showing anything

Tags: 18.04, git

Until a few days ago, my Git GUI was working properly. It was showing the  modified file names with a blue color on the left and the changes made on the right.

Since today, my Git GUI shows nothing on screen. I am not sure what I did on the previous days.

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-gui
$ sudo apt-get remove git-gui
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update Git GUI or did an upgrade with `sudo apt-get upgrade`?
Cleaning and reinstalling `git-gui` might work. So try running the following commands in a terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge git-gui
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git-gui
```